# R: WHILE LOOP Producing the Same Results

Tags: r, while-loop

I am working with the R programming language. In a previous question ([Do while loops store intermediate results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72847719/do-while-loops-store-intermediate-results)), I learned how to write my first WHILE LOOP:

```
list_results <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
    num_1_i = num_2_i = num_3_i = 0
    
    while(num_1_i + num_2_i + num_3_i < 150){
        num_1_i = sample(1:100 , 1)
        num_2_i = sample(1:100 , 1)
        num_3_i = sample(1:100 , 1)
    }
    
    inter_results_i <- data.frame(i, num_1_i, num_2_i, num_3_i)
    list_results[[i]] <- inter_results_i
}
```

I am now trying to modify this WHILE LOOP. I want to:

- Take 3 random samples from the "Iris Dataset"
- Take the average value of "Sepal.Length" from each of these 3 random samples
- Do this until the sum of these 3 average values is greater than 20
- Repeat all this 100 times

I tried to adapt the above code for this:

```
list_results <- list()
for (i in 1:100){

    ctotal_i = c1_i = c2_i = c3_i = 0
    
    while(ctotal_i < 20 ){


        num_1_i = sample(iris , replace = TRUE, 30)
        num_2_i = sample(iris , replace = TRUE, 30)
        num_3_i = sample(iris , replace = TRUE, 30)


c1_i = mean(num_1_i$Sepal.Length)
c2_i = mean(num_2_i$Sepal.Length)
c3_i = mean(num_3_i$Sepal.Length)
ctotal_i = c1_i + c2_i  + c3_i

    }
    
    inter_results_i <- data.frame(i, c1_i, c2_i, c3_i, ctotal_i)
    list_results[[i]] <- inter_results_i
}
```

But this is giving me the following error:

```
   Error in while (ctotal_i < 15) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(num_1_i$Sepal.Length) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how can I fix this problem?**

Thanks!

Comment: You are not taking random samples but random _columns_. Run `sample(iris , replace = TRUE, 30)` and look at the result. I guess that you meant `iris[sample(nrow(iris), replace = TRUE, 30), ]` or `iris[sample(nrow(iris ), 30), ]` (sampling without repetition).  Is that right?

Comment: @  
B. Christian Kamgang : Thank you for your reply! Your command gives me the row numbers - mine gives me a subset of columns/rows. I thought this should be ok, yes? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Here - I think I solved my own question! I used the "dplyr" sample function instead:

```
list_results <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
    
    c1_i = c2_i = c3_i = 0
    
    while(c1_i + c2_i  + c3_i < 15 ){
        
        
        num_1_i = sample_n(iris, 30)
        num_2_i = sample_n(iris, 30)
        num_3_i = sample_n(iris, 30)
        
        
        c1_i = mean(num_1_i$Sepal.Length)
        c2_i = mean(num_2_i$Sepal.Length)
        c3_i = mean(num_3_i$Sepal.Length)
        ctotal_i = c1_i + c2_i  + c3_i
        
    }
    
    inter_results_i <- data.frame(i, c1_i, c2_i, c3_i, ctotal_i)
    list_results[[i]] <- inter_results_i
}
```

For some reason, this works!